# Interpretation ambiguity

Tags: ambiguity, interpretation

While reading the article, I am quite confused about the part bolded "whether fallen or not".

I believe there might be two possible answers:

1: I did not stop to think whether the whirring cicadas was fallen or not.

2: I did not stop to think whether the angels was fallen or not.

**The article:**

The whirring cicadas might have been the rustling wings of angels -- I did not stop to think **whether fallen or not.**

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a clear reference to Satan/the Devil in the Bible who is described by some as a "fallen angel". The suggestion is that cicadas might perhaps be rather like devils than angels. The comparison is metaphorical, not literal.